# Не переносится поиск влево

Tags: html, вёрстка

`position: relative` не работает, при попытке перенести поиск вниз текста влево, вводя значения ничего не случается, закинул код на кодпен, вот ссылка:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/DEdadad/pen/KKzNoWG)

```
 /* Поле поиска с кнопкой-иконкой внутри*/
  form {
  /* Расположение поиска вместе с иконкой */
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 200px;
  top: 370px;

  
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Comment: Все работает, у вас просто мешанина в CSS, которая одну проблему наслаивает на другую.

Answer (score 1):

значение у left по умолчанию это - auto, а написано 0 и в то же время right 200px. Из-за этого и баг, скорее всего